# Pandas' ExcelWrite results in "'Workbook' object has no attribute 'add_worksheet'" and breaks excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I am trying to append a new sheet to an existing excel file while keeping the existing content within that excel file. I have taken several approaches to this task, but all of them result in the same error. I get some AttributeError when I try to write to the file or save the file and I get the same error message when trying to open the file.

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

file = "Budget 2021 copy.xlsx"
book = load_workbook(file)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file, engine = "xlsxwriter")
writer.book = book
​
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = "Test")
writer.save()
writer.close()
/Users/.../opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/xml/etree/ElementTree.py:1631: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedWriter name='Budget 2021 copy.xlsx'>
  return self.target.start(tag, attrib)
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
Exception ignored in: <function ZipFile.__del__ at 0x7ff88b71c310>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/zipfile.py", line 1821, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "/Users/.../opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/zipfile.py", line 1838, in close
    self.fp.seek(self.start_dir)
ValueError: seek of closed file
<ipython-input-56-a8797e939101>:9: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedWriter name='Budget 2021 copy.xlsx'>
  writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file, engine = "xlsxwriter")
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-a8797e939101> in <module>
     10 writer.book = book
     11 
---> 12 df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = "Test")
     13 writer.save()
     14 writer.close()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in to_excel(self, excel_writer, sheet_name, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, startrow, startcol, engine, merge_cells, encoding, inf_rep, verbose, freeze_panes, storage_options)
   2187             inf_rep=inf_rep,
   2188         )
-> 2189         formatter.write(
   2190             excel_writer,
   2191             sheet_name=sheet_name,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/excel.py in write(self, writer, sheet_name, startrow, startcol, freeze_panes, engine, storage_options)
    819 
    820         try:
--> 821             writer.write_cells(
    822                 formatted_cells,
    823                 sheet_name,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_xlsxwriter.py in write_cells(self, cells, sheet_name, startrow, startcol, freeze_panes)
    207             wks = self.sheets[sheet_name]
    208         else:
--> 209             wks = self.book.add_worksheet(sheet_name)
    210             self.sheets[sheet_name] = wks
    211 

AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'add_worksheet'
```

The same thing happens if I use openpyxl as engine, I get the error:

```py
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_tree'
```

which refers to:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-447977f76652> in <module>
     11 
     12 df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = "Test")
---> 13 writer.save()
     14 writer.close()
```

(I am not putting the whole traceback due to length, but I can do so if it might helps).

Comment: I don't think you can mix XLSX engines like this, nor should you want to.

Comment: @CharlieClark Might be the case, but when I use opnepyxl as engine, I still get the same error, as commented on in the last part of the post.

Comment: The exception is engine specific, so it can't be the same with openpyxl.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you have the following DataFrame with values.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
  "any_of_column_in_your_dframe" : ["ersingulbahar","yagiz","TS"],
  "calories": [420, 380, 390],
  "duration": [50, 40, 45]
}

#load data into a DataFrame object:
your_dframe = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

You can used the following function to append the sheet to an existing file.

```
def append_to_excel(file_name, new_df, sheet_name):
    # Open excel using Openpyxl in append mode
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, engine='openpyxl', mode='a')
    
    # Write to excel
    new_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
    
    # Save and close the excel file
    writer.save()
    writer.close()

append_to_excel('test.xlsx', your_dframe, 'NEW_SHEET')
```

Comment: If I see correctly, this code is mostly different from my code with the mode = "a" part? Adding that to the options in ExcelWriter makes no difference. I also checked just in case whether pasting your code exactly would yield the same error and it did.

Comment: @Benjamin I didn't understand? can you please elaborate your question.